# Offline journal app with strong metadata (attributes, tags) feature

Tags: open-source, metadata, journal

I'm looking for desktop journal (note-taking, diary) application where pages can be consisted of several entries and each entry can have its own attributes (tags, date).

Simple example: I am writing down what happened today and one entry (something that looks like paragraph in that text) can be tagged as "job". So, later I can be able to see all and only job related entries on Job page, one under another and should be displayed whole entries with their own text formatting. It's not acceptable solution where is displayed only the list of pages which are tagged as @job (like [zim wiki](http://www.zim-wiki.org/manual/Help/Tags.html) does).

Features:

- one entry can have multiple attributes (tags, date)
- tag hierarchy is desirable (job.idea, job.problems, job.meeting...)
- fast tagging and setting other attributes (existing tags should be displayed)
- basic text formatting and image insertion support
- calendar feature (displays all entries for selected day)
- complex queries (several tags, date range...) that can be saved for later reuse
- offline data storage (no clouds and servers)
- open-source

Can some [RDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) (semantic web) tool be useful for this purpose?

App doesn't have to be easy to learn.

Comment: https://tiddlywiki.com might fit your needs. You can script custom pages to display filtered entries by tag or date. It doesn't really have a calendar in the traditional sense, but you can search and filter by date.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, thank you! It seems pretty powerful. I'll try to find a convenient way to use it as journal. The only big problem is that it is not native desktop application. I've downloaded desktop version, but it's slow and it doesn't have classic desktop interface layout.